# App.Delegate TabController Swift

Tags: swift, appdelegate

[image: Error in App.Deleagte and Layou]

Hi..

I need to declare my Tab Controller in my App.deletgate as my rootcontroller but I also need to declare my managedObjectContext in my second View controller. Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

I have put an image to my project structure above

App.Delegate with Errors
    import UIKit
    import CoreData

```
 @UIApplicationMain
  class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


   func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let rootNavigationController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("StoryboardIDRootNavigationController") as! UITabBarController

    // Configure View Controller
    let viewController = window?.rootViewController as? ViewController

    if let viewController = viewController{
        viewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext
    }

    // Configure Window
    window?.rootViewController = rootNavigationController

 return true

}
```

Answer (score 0):

UITabbarController has a **viewControllers** property which is an array of the root view controllers displayed by the tab bar. You can use this to get the controller at the second index.

> The default value of this property is nil. When configuring a tab bar controller, you can use this property to specify the content for each tab of the tab bar interface. The order of the view controllers in the array corresponds to the display order in the tab bar. Thus, the controller at index 0 corresponds to the left-most tab, the controller at index 1 the next tab to the right, and so on. If there are more view controllers than can fit in the tab bar, view controllers at the end of the array are managed by the More navigation controller, which is itself not included in this array.

```
let tabController = UITabBarController()

class CustomViewController: UIViewController {
  var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext?
}

if let viewController = tabController.viewControllers?[1] as? CustomViewController {
  viewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext
}
```

Comment: can u give an example?

Comment: Do you have a core data stack set up? If yes, where did you initialize it?